# Select a variable randomly, but all variables should be equally selected from an array

Tags: php, drupal, web-applications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [select a variable randomly, but each varaible should be equally selected from an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11858330/select-a-variable-randomly-but-each-varaible-should-be-equally-selected-from-an)

I need a function (preferably PHP) which randomly select a variable from an array at a time but satisfying the below condition. Suppose I have 3 variables in the array. each time it should select one variable. but if i execute the function for 10 times, each variable should be selected for atleast 3 times each. ie. all variables should be equally selected at the end I cannot remove or unset any variable from the array because the execution of the function happens in page refresh, so the array will contain all values

See people, I know i can use array_rand function in php to randomly select a variable. here it doesn't assure that i can achieve the above logic ( each variable should be selected for atleast 3 times each if i execute this function for 10 times).

other way i can make use of session. but i am asking for to see if there is any other way around instead of using session or cookies.

example :  i executed this function for 10 times. here what happens is like '1' got displayed for 5 times, '2' got displayed for 3 times and '3' got displayed for 2 times. but is there any possibility to make it display for 3 times each ???

Comment: The last question was closed a few minutes ago, okay, you have added some comments around array_rand and sessions. Have a go at writing it, think through the process of how you can make it work. When you get *somewhere* with that, post some code and explain where it is going wrong. Then you might get some help with it.

Comment: <?php
$input_arr = array("1", "2", "3");
$num=Rand(0,3);
echo $input_arr[$num];
?> i executed this function for 10 times. here what happens is like  '1'  got displayed for 5 times, '2' got displayed for 3 times and '3' got displayed for 2 times. but is there any possibility to make it display for 3 times each ???

Answer (score 2):

You have defined mutually exclusive requirements: 'randomly select', and 'equally selected' (or 'evenly distributed')! You can't do both.

Comment: I believe they call that [Inverse Transform Sampling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling)

Answer (score 1):

[That](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-rand.php) is what you need : `array_rand`

Example :

```
<?php
$input = array("Neo", "Morpheus", "Trinity", "Cypher", "Tank");
$rand_keys = array_rand($input, 1);
echo $input[$rand_keys[0]] . "\n";
?>
```